# When creating a Server Sent Event and using MogoDB Change Streams I am getting additive duplication of data when refreshing the browser

Tags: angular, mongodb, server-sent-events, changestream

I don't know if this is a serious concern because the app is not designed for people constantly refreshing the app while doing data updates. But It still feels like code smell and seems like an apparent memory leak.

What is happening specifically is that during a connection to a MongoDB `changeStream` If I refresh the app and then update the data when it fires through the connection the data is duplicated and it is additive to how many times I refresh. So if I refresh the browser 5 times then the data that would pipe through on a data update would be 5 sets of the same data coming through the stream.

On the face of it I don't think this is MongoDB's `changeStream` that is doing it but I am not 100% sure. When I use the `changeStream` on it's own, without the SSE connection, that doesn't occur. It is a 1 to 1 change as expected no matter how many times I refresh the browser.

What I believe would alleviate the issue is that upon closing the browser or refreshing it which fires a connection closed event I could end the SSE connection and restart it or refresh it.  But, when I close the SSE connection from the client it does't re-establish upon the reset of the refresh. I believe closing the connection would clear out the stream and start fresh but I am not sure.

The architecture is as follows. There is a route that is setup as an Server Sent Event SSE that connects an endpoint to An Angular client.

```js
exports.GetCovid19InitialUserStream = (req, res) => {
    initialize(req, res);
}

const initialize = (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.flushHeaders(); // flush the headers to establish SSE with client
    res.write("retry: 5000\n\n");

    client.connect( err => {
        const collection = client.db(dbName);
        ....
        testthis(collection, res);
    });
    subject.subscribe({
        next: (v) => {
            console.log(`observerA: ${JSON.stringify(v)}`);
            res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(v)}\n\n`);
            // res.end();
            // return;
        },
        complete: () => console.log('COMPLETE ')
      });

    res.on('close', () => {
        console.log('client dropped me');
        // clearInterval(interValID);
        // res.end();
    });
}
```

Here is the `changeStream` code:

```js
const subject = new Subject<any>();
const testthis = async (client, res) => {
    const collection = client.collection(documentName);
    const changeStreamIterator = collection.watch({ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });

    changeStreamIterator.on('change', next => {
        console.log('THIS IS NEXT ============================== ', next.fullDocument);
        subject.next(next.fullDocument);
        // res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(next.fullDocument)}\n\n`); // res.write() instead of res.send()
        // return next.fullDocument;
        // process next document
      });
    // while(true) {
    //     const next = await changeStreamIterator.next();
    //     subject.next(next);
    // }

}
```

And the client code is as follows:

```js
 getServerSentEvent(url?: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (this.isBrowser) {
        this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          const eventSource: EventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
          eventSource.onmessage = event => {
            console.log('event ', event);
            this._zone.run(() => {
              // console.log('event.lastEventId ', event.lastEventId);
              // if (event.lastEventId === '-1') {
              //   console.log('I should CLOSE --------- ', event.lastEventId);
              // }
              observer.next(event);

            });
          };
          // eventSource.close();
          eventSource.onerror = error => {
            console.log('this is the error ', error);
            this._zone.run(() => {
              // observer.error(error);
              // if I close then there can be no more messages sent
              // eventSource.close();
            });
          };
        })
      }


    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      console.log('this happened here 2');
      return new EventSource(url);
    }

  }
```

I don't know if it is a big deal or if I should ignore it because the likelyhood of it happening is so small but I feel like something is wrong with the setup and I either need to close the SSE connection and refresh or restart it or something else.

Comment: Are you saying you get the same change from the same change stream more than once?

Comment: @D.SM yes but it's all at once. It's not flushing from the server like a setinterval would do with a clearinterval operation. So if I refresh or come back to do a data change the result shows up multiple times

Comment: What is all at once and what is not flushing? Most likely either you are trying to resume the change stream at a point from which you already read results or you have multiple change streams active in which case they could each return the same change.

Comment: @D.SM I just have data coming from mondb changestream into a feed. The connection to the SSE client is getting data changes per user, per event channel on the stream.  So the data is only in regards to that signed in user. If I refresh the page and I make a data change the id will be 1, 2 of the same data. if I refresh again the id will be 1, 2, 3 all of the same data. If I refresh a fourth time and do a data change it will come back 1, 2, 3, 4 all the same data